# Can I compile an Outlook addin project using VisualStudio 2015 build tools only?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vsto, build-tools

I am trying to compile an Outlook addin project (created using VS2015) on a windows server which has visual studio 2015 build tools installed (no VS 2015 IDE). During compilation I get the following error:

> The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\OfficeTools\Micro‌​soft.VisualStudio.To‌​ols.Office.Targets" was not found. Confirm that path in  declaration is correct, and the file exists on disk.

Can I compile an Outlook addin project using VS2015 build tools only?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Targets" was not found. Confirm that path in <import> declaration is correct, and the file exists on disk. The file obviously doesnt exist on the disk since I only have VS2015 build tools installed.

Comment: you need to follow the step explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff624126.aspx) and this might be handy as well: https://github.com/mrdavidlaing/AMEEInExcel/tree/master/tools/vsto2010. For both link goes: adapt for VS2015 where needed.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try.